# Error launching opencv after spring boot startup

Tags: java, spring, opencv, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm using spring tool suite to create a spring boot back-end calling opencv.
I made a class with a sample code to test opencv as follow:

```
@Service
public class opencvTests {
    @PostConstruct
    public static void mymethod(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat m  = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println("m = " + m.dump());

        return;
    }
}
```

And when I call directly the method in the main method of my app, it works well but prevents spring boot to launch properly.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OpencvTestingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        opencvTests.mymethod()
        SpringApplication.run(OpencvTestingApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Therefore I used the *@PostConstruct* annotation to launch the method when spring boot is running but... it fails on the matrix object call like the opencv library wasn't already loaded. I tried several alternatives such as using the *ApplicationReadyEvent* but the issue persists. (precision: the opencv jar is already added to the project and the opencv libraries path is added as a parameter to maven)

```
Welcome to OpenCV 3.2.0-dev
/home/*****/opencv/build/lib
2017-05-26 03:37:09.475  WARN 14951 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'opencvTests': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(III)J
2017-05-26 03:37:09.522  INFO 14951 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-05-26 03:37:09.559 ERROR 14951 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'opencvTests': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(III)J
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
at be.heh.opencvtesting.OpencvTestingApplication.main(OpencvTestingApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(III)J
at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(Native Method) ~[opencv-320.jar:na]
at org.opencv.core.Mat.eye(Mat.java:492) ~[opencv-320.jar:na]
at be.heh.opencvtesting.opencvTests.mymethod(opencvTests.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
... 22 common frames omitted
```

I still have much to learn with both opencv and spring boot, unfortunately I couldn't find any working solution on stackoverflow or google.
Could someone please indicate me a useful workaround? I would be really thankful as this project is quite important for me.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I don't really have the answer :-( ... But, have you tried using the opencv library outside of spring boot, in a 'plain' java project? My instinct here is to first try and get it running without the extra distraction of fitting your initialization logic inside of spring-boot. Once you understand exactly the sequence of steps that needs to happen to get it setup in working condition, you can return to trying to fit those steps into `@PostConstruct` or some other kind of mechanics you can use to execute bits of code at specific times in spring boot.

Comment: BTW, perusing your sample code, I see you are calling 'mymethod' at the start of your main *before* starting the spring boot application (with `SpringApplication.run`) so probably that is the problem. You are calling your method before your app has even started, so spring boot really has had no chance yet to run those `@PostConstruct` method in your app. In fact it hasn't had any chance to do anything at all.

Comment: Thank you Kris, but that line is commented when I run it after spring (otherwise @PostConstruct is commented). I picked this form to show both cases because the issue is: Spring doesn't launch if opencv I run an opencv function first, or opencv lib path isn't found if I launch it after :/